# How to set the main monitor on Lubuntu?

Tags: ati, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I have a desktop computer with Lubuntu and a dualhead display (two monitors). I want to extend the display to both monitors (currently they're mirrored), but I have a problem: the left monitor is a 19", and the right one is a 24".

If I use the standard Lubuntu tool to setup the extended display, the main screen is **always** the left monitor, and because it's smaller than the right one, some parts (like the bottom Lubuntu's bar) can't be seen.

How can I set the right monitor as the main screen, so the bottom bar appears only on this screen and the desktop is extended to the 19" monitor at the left of the main screen? Is it possible? In Windows 7 it works correctly, but I need this in Lubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

To establish dual monitors with LXDE, install Arandr from Synaptics.  Then follow the instructions in this "How To".
http://lxlinux.com/#14

Comment: I've already installed Arandr, but this tool sets as a main monitor the left one, and I need the right one...